# Highlight table cells in Word 2010 that have tracked changes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking to highlight table cells with tracked changes.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub HiliteChanges()

Dim oTable As Table
Dim oColumn As Column
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oRange As Range
Dim numRevs As Integer
Dim tableIndex, rowIndex, cellIndex As Integer

For tableIndex = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    For rowIndex = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(tableIndex).Rows.Count
        For cellIndex = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(tableIndex).Rows(rowIndex).Cells.Count
            numRevs = ActiveDocument.Tables(tableIndex).Rows(rowIndex).Cells(cellIndex).Range.Revisions.Count
            Debug.Print tableIndex, rowIndex, cellIndex, numRevs
            If numRevs > 0 Then
                ActiveDocument.Tables(tableIndex).Rows(rowIndex).Cells(cellIndex).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlueGray
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

What it ends up doing is highlighting the entire row, even if only one cell in a row is changed.

I made a change in a table with 3 rows and 6 columns.  The change was in the fourth column of the first row.  I turned off Track Changes prior to running the script.  This was the output:

```
1             1             1             1 
1             1             2             1 
1             1             3             1 
1             1             4             1 
1             1             5             1 
1             1             6             1 
1             2             1             0 
1             2             2             0 
1             2             3             0 
1             2             4             0 
1             2             5             0 
1             2             6             0 
1             3             1             0 
1             3             2             0 
1             3             3             0 
1             3             4             0 
1             3             5             0 
1             3             6             0
```

So it looks like every cell in the first row has a change, but it doesn't.  There was only one cell with a change.

Is there a way to highlight only the cells that have changes?  (Obviously my way is flawed in some way, but I can't see where.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check for revisions, don't include the "end of cell" marker in the checked range.  Don't ask me why that works...

```
Sub HiliteChanges()

    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oColumn As Column, oRow As Row, rng As Range
    Dim oCell As Cell
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim numRevs As Integer
    Dim tableIndex, rowIndex, cellIndex As Integer

    For tableIndex = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

        Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(tableIndex)

        For rowIndex = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count

            Set oRow = oTable.Rows(rowIndex)

            For cellIndex = 1 To oRow.Cells.Count

                Set oCell = oRow.Cells(cellIndex)


                Set rng = oCell.Range
                'don't include the "end of cell" marker in the checked range
                rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1

                numRevs = rng.Revisions.Count

                Debug.Print tableIndex, rowIndex, cellIndex, numRevs

                If numRevs > 0 Then
                    oCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlueGray
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  (And also thank you for showing me a nicer way to refer to things in the inner loops!)